# ¿Cómo muestro un formulario m2m en django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

Estoy intentando que un usuario pueda modificar su perfil.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A la derecha vemos como el usuario tiene asociadas dos monedas: Bitcoin y Ethereum y una casa de cambio: Coinbase

El objetivo es que en el formulario de la izquierda el usuario pueda cambiar sus datos y añadir o quitarse monedas y monederos (casas de cambio).

Necesito:

1. Saber cómo gestionar eso con los campos **ModelMultipleChoiceField**
2. Cómo mostrar en los campos el valor actual, por ejemplo en el input de Name debería mostrar **antonigalile** y en el email **email@gmail.com**

Me gustaría que el seleccionador de monedas y wallets quede como este: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí van mis ficheros:

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.timezone import now
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser


class Coin(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True,max_length=50)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    transaction_fee = models.FloatField(default=0.0,blank=True)
    price = models.FloatField(default=0.0,blank=True)
    market_cap = models.IntegerField(default=0,blank=True)
    volume = models.IntegerField(default=0,blank=True)
    circulating = models.IntegerField(default=0,blank=True)
    change = models.FloatField(default=0.0,blank=True)
    def __str__(self): 
        return self.name

class Wallet(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True,max_length=50)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    coins = models.ManyToManyField(Coin)
    def __str__(self): 
        return self.name

class Usuario(AbstractUser):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=12, help_text="The name must be between 2 and 12 characters")
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=60, unique=True, help_text="The email must be between 5 and 30 characters")
    password = models.CharField(max_length=78)
    change_password_code = models.CharField(blank=True,max_length=15)
    activated = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    activated_code = models.CharField(default="",max_length=15)
    ip = models.CharField(blank=True,max_length=15)
    last_login = models.DateField(default=now)
    wallets = models.ManyToManyField(Wallet)
    coins = models.ManyToManyField(Coin)
    avatar = models.CharField(blank=True,default="bitcoin.png",max_length=15)
    delete_code = models.CharField(default="",max_length=9,blank=True)
    two_factors_auth = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    two_factors_auth_code = models.CharField(default="",max_length=12,blank=True)
    fingerprint = models.CharField(max_length=64,blank=True)
```

**forms.py**

```
class EditProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Usuario
        exclude = ()
    wallets = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Wallet.objects.all(),to_field_name="name")
    name = forms.CharField(label='Name')
    email = forms.EmailField(label='Email')
    two_factors_auth = forms.BooleanField()
    coins = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Coin.objects.all(),to_field_name="name")
```

**form.html**

```
<form method="post">
     {% csrf_token %}
     <div class="form-group">
         <p> {{ edit_profile_form.name.label }} </p>
         {% render_field edit_profile_form.name class+="form-control" %}
         {{ edit_profile_form.name.errors }}
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
         <p> {{ edit_profile_form.email.label }} </p>
         {% render_field edit_profile_form.email class+="form-control" %}
         {{ edit_profile_form.email.errors }}
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
         <p>My Wallets</p>
         {{ edit_profile_form.wallets}}
         {{ edit_profile_form.wallets.errors }}
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
         <p>My Coins</p>
         {{ edit_profile_form.coins }}
         {{ edit_profile_form.coins.errors }}
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
        <p>Activate two factor authentication
        {{ edit_profile_form.two_factors_auth }}</p>
        {{ edit_profile_form.two_factors_auth.errors }}
    </div>
    <button type="submit" name="profileButton" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
</form>
```

**views.py** (aún sin terminar)

```
class userPageView(TemplateView):
template_name = 'user.html'

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['edit_profile_form'] = EditProfileForm(prefix='contact')
    return context

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return render(request, 'user.html')
```

¿Qué puedo hacer?
Gracias

Comment: pues la verdad yo he realizado algo de ello pero he usado jqgrid ..javascript..ajax..jquery

Comment: http://www.guriddo.net/demo/guriddojs/

Comment: en la Parte de Integrations->Drag and drop rows between grids

Comment: Gracias @Tegito123 pero pasar lo que recoja ese plugin a django va a ser más lioso que intentar implementar el que trae django para los permisos de usuario

Comment: Pues por lo visto estás mostrando bien el formulario. ¿Tu problema es implementar el `post`?

Comment: Mi problema es que el selector no es intuitivo y que selecciono por ejemplo tres monedas y el post solo recibe la última.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A mi pregunta sobre cómo gestionar la selección de coins con un formulario ManyToMany:

Pulsando CTRL+click izquierdo sobre la moneda elegida es como se seleccionan.

A mi pregunta sobre hacer que el valor que tiene el usuario en su base de datos aparezca por defecto en el formulario:

resuelto desde Jquery